# Catch REFERENCE constraint exception from SQL in C#

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

What will be proper way to catch exception which throw SQL server when I deleting data with Reference constraint from C# code.
I want to show my users message like:
 *"I can't delete the data because is used"*
, rather than of showing message like this:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint ... The conflict ccurred*in database "rampa", table "dbo.doc", column 'kartica_id'.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
try
{
   //Execute delete statement
}
catch (SqlException sqlEx)
{
   //Handle exception
}
finally
{
   //Close connection
}
```

All sql errors are thrown as `SqlException` and there are no specific errors. To find out what was error exactly, there is property `SqlException.Number` which is the same as SQL Error Code. You can find the list of codes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors).

Comment: Your conclusion "there are no specific errors" is in conflict with Steve Townsend answer, thank you anyway +1 for link with error codes

Comment: Well, ConstraintException is not actualy caught by executing SQLCommands but rather by using dataadapters - it handles SQLException and throws as ConstraintException

Comment: @adopilot - @Ivan is correct here.  How you must handle this depends on your ADO.Net usage.  Different for SqlClient.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the [ConstraintException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.constraintexception.aspx) and map its fields however you want to your own preferred error output.

```
using System.Data;

try
{
  // code that violates constraint
}
catch (ConstraintException exc)
{
  // build output message you wish using exc.Message and other fields,
  // return cleanly or rethrow as your own exception
}
```